# SQL join - joining two complete queries

Tags: sql, join

I believe there is a simple solution but for some reason I am not getting it to work

I am working to join two query with an inner join

first query:

```
select *
from edl_views.oca_orders_opt_cd_ex as oca
```

second query:

```
(select *
from edl_current.core_product_master_piprod as hdr
inner join edl_current.core_product_master_prodcmpntasscn as cpt
  on hdr.prod_id = cpt.prod_id
where hdr.pin_17 is not null
and cpt.comp_typ_cd = "ED") as PI
```

I need all of the first query joined with the second query by the pin or:

```
(select *
from edl_current.core_product_master_piprod as hdr
inner Join edl_current.core_product_master_prodcmpntasscn as cpt
on hdr.prod_id = cpt.prod_id
where hdr.pin_17 is not null
and cpt.comp_typ_cd = "ED") as PI
inner join
select *
from edl_views.oca_orders_opt_cd_ex as oca
on oca.pin_17 = PI.hdr.pin_17
```

my version is providing errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: _my version is providing errors_ Are we supposed to guess what they are??  Please share the full error message.

Comment: the error   
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'as'.(line 6, pos 28)

== SQL ==
(select *
from edl_current.core_product_master_piprod as hdr
inner Join edl_current.core_product_master_prodcmpntasscn as cpt
on hdr.prod_id = cpt.prod_id
where hdr.pin_17 is not null
and cpt.comp_typ_cd = "ED") as PI
----------------------------^^^
inner join
select *
from edl_views.oca_orders_opt_cd_ex as oca
on oca.pin_17 = PI.hdr.pin_17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors: Brackets are misplaced/missing and text literals are delimited by apostrophes not quotes (ie you should use `'ED'`; don't use `"ED"`).

You also don't need (and shouldn't use) subqueries.

```
select *
from edl_current.core_product_master_piprod as hdr
join edl_current.core_product_master_prodcmpntasscn as cpt
  on hdr.prod_id = cpt.prod_id
  and cpt.comp_typ_cd = 'ED'
join edl_views.oca_orders_opt_cd_ex as oca
  on oca.pin_17 = hdr.pin_17
where hdr.pin_17 is not null
```

Note also moving condition `cpt.comp_typ_cd = 'ED'` into the join and removing redundant `inner` keyword (all joins are inner joins unless a accompanied by a `left`,  `right` or `cross` keyword)

Comment: this got me a lot further, thank you very much!!!